# Remove terminal border colors from vim colorschemes

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I want the color scheme to span completely across the terminal boundaries. I am using Color Scheme Scroller Plugin to switch between different theme. I have uploaded a .gif file so that you can clearly see what I want to get fixed. Vim colorschemes doesn't completely change the color of editor. There are some terminal color's borders left around the vim's overridden color scheme. How would I fix it.

Please check the image on [this](http://cl.ly/dsYR#) link. Stackoverflow doesn't allow uploading an image > 2Mb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that from Vim itself.

Terminal emulators use that padding to preserve readability when characters are displayed next to the borders of the window. The programs you run in your terminal have no knowledge of that padding and thus no ability to change it.

But you can read the documentation of your terminal emulator or take a look at its source code to find a way to enable/adjust/disable that padding.

FWIW, there's no way to change that in Terminal but [it can be done for iTerm.](https://superuser.com/a/872432/60075)

Alternatively, you could simply set the background color of your terminal to the one used in your vim colorscheme.

Answer (score 1):

The image appears to depict behavior outside vim's control:

- it is using a terminal emulator (could be xterm, could be some other).
- the terminal emulator draws character cells on a window
- those cells form a grid; the window may extend beyond the grid
- the window can have a background color
- the grid can have a background color
- within the grid, most terminals provide some capability of drawing text with specific foreground and background colors
- the grid can have a default background color which is not any of the specified colors
- outside the grid, the window can also have a default background color
- normally, the grid- and window-default backgrounds are the same
- the window can be resized to (more or less) arbitrary sizes
- the grid is constrained to exact character sizes
- because of this difference, the window can have areas outside the grid which use its default color, and not match the grid's background color.
- escape sequences which could affect the grid- and window-background colors are doing *erases* (see for example the ncurses FAQ *[My terminal shows some uncolored spaces](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bce_mismatches)*).
- though it is conceivable that erasures within the grid could affect those outside areas, doing *that* generally leads to odd visual effects.